# Scikit-Learn grid search with custom CountVectorizer tokenizer

Tags: python, multithreading, scikit-learn, nltk

I am currently learning more about scikit learn and nltk and I am building a text classifier.

I am not a python expert but I am learning as I go (I do have backgrounds in various other programming languages)

Now, I have this code which performs a grid search for the best parameters for my classification pipeline. I omitted some of the parameters to illustrate the issue better.

Take for example the following code where I optimize the "C" parameter of the LinearSVC classifier.

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vect', CountVectorizer()),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
    ('clf', LinearSVC()),
])

parameters = {
    'clf__C': (5, 3, 1),
}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # multiprocessing requires the fork to happen in a __main__ protected
    # block

    # find the best parameters for both the feature extraction and the
    # classifier
    grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, n_jobs=-1, verbose=1)

    print("Performing grid search...")
    print("pipeline:", [name for name, _ in pipeline.steps])
    print("parameters:")
    pprint(parameters)
    t0 = time()
    grid_search.fit(data.Phrase, data.Sentiment)
    print("done in %0.3fs" % (time() - t0))
    print()

    print("Best score: %0.9f" % grid_search.best_score_)
    print("Best parameters set:")
    best_parameters = grid_search.best_estimator_.get_params()
    for param_name in sorted(parameters.keys()):
        print("\t%s: %r" % (param_name, best_parameters[param_name]))
```

This code works fine, but if I want to use a custom tokenizer/analyzer/... the grid search will fail, probably because of the multithreading.

As you may know, scikit learn requires the tokenizer to be a callable class if custom made. Here is for example the LemmaTokenizer from the docs:

```
class LemmaTokenizer(object):
 def __init__(self):
     self.wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
 def __call__(self, doc):
     return [self.wnl.lemmatize(t) for t in wordpunct_tokenize(doc)]
```

Now, using just the pipeline with this class works perfectly by changing my pipeline into this:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vect', CountVectorizer(tokenizer=LemmaTokenizer())),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
    ('clf', LinearSVC()),
])
```

However, if I want to perform the same grid search with this custom tokenizer, it fails and gives me the following output:

```
Performing grid search...
pipeline: ['vect', 'tfidf', 'clf']
parameters:
{'tfidf__norm': ('l1', 'l2')}
Fitting 3 folds for each of 2 candidates, totalling 6 fits
Exception in thread Thread-6:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 342, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.instancemethod failed
```

My guess is the class instance gets lost somewhere?

I am using the latest stable scikit-learn 1.4

Comment: Where exactly in your code are you definining your custom class?

Comment: Seems to work fine on Linux w/ latest scikit-learn dev version, and I don't recall major changes to this subsystem since 0.14.1.

Comment: The problem is apparently in this line:

self.wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()

I suppose it would be better anyways to pass an instance of a WordNetLemmatizer instead of creating a new one for every LemmaTokenizer instance.

However I have cases where I would like to pass parameters for a grid search to a new instance, how would I do that then?

Comment: Please include import statements and toy hardcoded data (e.g. a Python list with 3 strings) in your code snippet so that people can quickly reproduce the problem with a simple copy & paste.